# GDB setting multiple breakpoints

Tags: c, gdb

I would like to set multiple breakpoints at once in different files in GDB.

Is it possible to have a script or any other way which I can run once I enter GDB debugger and have all the breakpoints set instead of setting them one by one using traditional `set break` command.

All the resources I searched pointed to how to set breakpoints effectively. But, nothing seems to address my concern.

Comment: Have you tried looking in [the GDB documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [source command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html) in gdb.

You can also put the commands in the *.gdbinit* file which will be sourced when you start gdb.  Put the commands there and they will be run without doing anything more.

Comment: If you are trying to set breakpoints on a library that will be loaded in the future, add 
```set breakpoint pending on``` to the top of that source-file, or else gdb will reject the breakpoints since they are not found.